# I need to use sudo for any Hadoop operation, how to change permissions?

Tags: command-line, 13.04, permissions, sudo, hadoop

I am self learning Hadoop, starting yesterday.
For the purpose of learning, I have set up Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on VMWare Fusion on my MacBook Pro. And I am following [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) excellent tutorial. Before this I have never used Ubuntu as a development platform.

So far I have managed to set up Hadoop and have successfully run the WordCount example. But along the way, I have to use `sudo` to do anything, e.g. starting up Hadoop services:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/start-all.sh
```

never works, giving exceptions, but
    sudo /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/bin/start-all.sh
works fine. Same is the case with `stop-all.sh` and for practically anything else.

Additionally, while starting Hadoop services, the OS asks for password multiple times (once before starting each component) and same happens when I use `stop-all.sh`.

I could not copy the downloaded files to `/usr/local/hadoop` using the UI. I had to copy them using the terminal using `sudo`.

If I open '/usr/local' in the UI, there is no permission to copy, move, delete or create new folder. And I searched how to change permissions, but for this folder, the owner is not the logged in user, but it was root, so the UI for setting permissions was disabled. And one cannot log in as root and use the UI logged in as root.

Also when came the stage of adding congfigurations to `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh`, `conf/mapred-site.xml` and `conf/hdfs-site.xml`, I could not save the edits using GEdit, and had to make changes using `nano` (preceded by `sudo`), which was again due to permissions.

One thing different in my setup is that instead of `/usr/local/hadoop/`, I have used `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-1.1.2/` as the extraction folder of Hadoop.

My questions are:

1. How to add to permissions so that I can use the UI, and GEdit or any
   editor of my choice?
2. How to make all the commands run without `sudo`?
3. And a slightly non-related question, what is the best IDE for
   Hadoop? Coming from Visual Studio and XCode, I am looking for a free
   IDE which I can use while getting used to of doing things using the
   terminal and using GEdit for simple changes in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
chown -R yourusername /usr/local/hadoop
```

to sort the permissions? This should change ownership of those folders and files to your user, allowing you to change things in those folders without using root/sudo.

Regarding an IDE, I have nothing but good words for Geany IDE: www.geany.org